# Optimize routine in R

Tags: r, optimization

I'm new to programming in R and I have a problem which I summarize in this small routine. It seems very simple for the time it takes... around 15 minutes for 500 iterations. How could I speed it up? Thanks in advance!.

EDIT:
It is a routine calculation of probabilities that simulates a sample (500) of a product of conditional probabilities (on pD.max.S1.i). The problem has large dimensions due to the combinatorics of d, a and s. that is why I looked for any idea about the structures (data.frame, for) that I use in the routine because it seems slow to run, and the possibility that other structures would be more optimal.

```
ncd = 3; nud = 4; nua = 2
pD.max.S1.i <- matrix( c( 0.00, 0.95, 0.99,                                             
                          0.00, 0.80, 0.95,
                          0.00, 0.50, 0.70,
                          0.00, 0.25, 0.30,
                          0.00, 0.00, 0.10),
                          nrow = nud + 1, ncol = nua + 1, byrow = T)    # probabilidades
rownames(pD.max.S1.i) = paste("d", 0 : nud, sep = "")
colnames(pD.max.S1.i) = paste("a", 0 : nua, sep = "")
pD.max.S1.i=as.data.frame(pD.max.S1.i)

d = expand.grid(0 : 4, 0 : 4, 0 : 4)
d = d[rowSums (d) == nud,]
rownames(d) = paste0("d", apply(d, 1, paste0, collapse=""))

a = expand.grid(0 : 2 ,0 : 2 ,0 : 2)
a = a[rowSums (a) <= nua,]
rownames(a) = paste0("a", apply(a, 1, paste0, collapse=""))     

s = expand.grid(0 : 1, 0 : 1, 0 : 1)
rownames(s) = paste0("s", apply(s, 1, paste0, collapse=""))

fun.prd.pA = function(pA, idp, idr, idc, ncd){ # productorio de probabilidades
    ppA = 1
    for (i in 1 : ncd) {
        ppi = pA[idr[1,i] + 1, idc[1,i] + 1]
        if (idp[1,i] == 0) ppi = 1 - ppi
        ppA = ppA * ppi
    }
    return(ppA)
}

for (ite in 1: 500) {
    for (xd1 in rownames(d)){ 
        for (xaa in rownames(a)){
            for (xs1 in rownames(s)){
                p1 = fun.prd.pA (pD.max.S1.i, s[xs1,], d[xd1,], a[xaa,], ncd)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to think in vectors. Start with fun.prd.pA and think how you could do the whole vector at once. Read the first couple chapters of this book to get started: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Data-structures.html

Comment: It would be easier if you''d explain what you are trying to do and what is the desired output.

Comment: Jeff Atwood of Coding Horrors blog/fame in his piece "You can write FORTRAN in any language" cites: Dikstra: http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~evans/cs655-S00/readings/ewd498.html . The point is not that FORTRAN is slow but that not all languages (and especially not R) support the optimization that is built into the compilers.

Comment: Not knowing what you are trying to do makes things more difficult. Excluding the `for` `iter`, the other 3 `for`s give you 1200 combinations, of which 840 are zero, so you need to think only in the 360 different from zero. Try to get `fun.prd.pA` smarter.

Comment: Thanks all for your comments, I will try to make it work another way to save not necessary loops